# UICollectionView dynamically resize section

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I'm implementing dragging of cells inside the section. This part is done, but I also need to resize section dynamically, so when user drag a cell all other cells kinda slide apart.
Changing `layoutAttributes.frame` in `layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:` and `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:` does not affect section. I think changing spacing between items in section should force section to resize, but I can't find out the way to change spacing dynamically. Can anyone suggest anything, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I didn't find better solution than to change value, returned by `collectionView:layout:minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:` dynamically and call `invalidateLayout`. I didn't try to change cells sizes as this effect was enough for me.

Comment: which flowlayout were you using to accomplish the smooth transition of being able to drag cells from one section to the other? I cant remember but I remember someone mentioning two flowlayouts but both were a bit glitchy and not so smooth. whenever you get time, let us know! cheers.

Comment: I wasn't trying to achieve dragging between sections, so can't answer

Comment: I just meant the act of dragging overall :) if you could comment on that for the libraries or something like that used. Because dragging cells ROCK!

Comment: Just a regular Flow Layout with custom behavior, you can check Apple's WWDC 2012 sample code (205 - Introducing Collection Views), they have sample with dragging. I don't have direct link, you'll have to search for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
[yourCollectionView reloadData];
```

Visible cells will be updated.

Comment: Didn't work for me. As my data is not changed cells are kept the same, and I needed to resize section. I achieved this effect by changing spacing between lines and calling invalidateLayout.